# mongodb.conf or mongod.conf - MongoDB conifguration on Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Tags: linux, mongodb, yaml, config, debian-stretch

After installing mongodb on `Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)` according to the offical mongodb guide on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/, I noticed the existence of two config files: `/etc/mongod.conf` and `/etc/mongodb.conf`.

Now I wonder whether they are supposed to coexist, be used simultaneously, where the *apparently inofficial* `mongodb.conf` comes from, whether one is deprecated or invalid, or if one takes presence over the other in case their config rules conflict.

Also, I noticed that `/etc/mongod.conf` appears to be in `YAML format`, while `/etc/mongodb.conf` appears to be in `INI format`.

I guess that `/etc/mongodb.conf` has been placed there during install of `mongodb-org` by dpkg, but it'd be nonetheless helpful if anybody could provide further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the purpose of the discrepancy is for the hardcore RTFM people. every version of MongoDB I install gives me the MongoDB.conf and yet every single documentation page references the YAML mongod.conf and the only other article that mentions this is from 2014.

Comment: I think this gives you an idea of the quality behind yet another crappy open source project